# blender doesnt recognize AMD radeon 780M

Tags: rendering, gpu

when i open blender on windows, it doesnt recognize `AMD radeon`, i can tick it but then i get `HIP kernal for this graphics card compute capability not found, not sure why`, i wanted to use it on ubuntu as well, but i dont have that option, maybe because i need to install additional package.

Not sure why window see the `AMD radeon` but i can't use it to render, any idea? if i buy an egpu do you think i can easily render?

Still a `noob` in blender, i started to use it recently[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpq72.jpg)[image]